# Who found the formula for sequential Stern-Gerlach experiments and when?

Tags: physics

Today we know that if you make sequential Stern-Gerlach experiments, where the magnetic fields are at an angle $\alpha$, then the formula for the ratio how the beam splits is
$$p_{1}=\cos^2 \bigg(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigg)$$
for one side and
$$p_{2}=1-p_{1}=\sin^2 \bigg(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigg)
$$
for the other side.

I understand this, but what I want to know is: Who discovered this formula?

I don't think Stern and Gerlach found it, because they don't mention it [in their original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.11343.pdf), and I suspect it was already known by the time Pauli discovered his matrices, so it seems this formula was found sometime between 1922 and 1924, but in my research I cannot find any mention of who found it

If one of you could please give me a source where they talk about this development, I would be really thankful.

Comment: You suspect that it was already known by the time of Pauli? Have you check his papers? I think that the two-state quantum system might have been developed before but it is quick tricky to look for it.